# How to compare value in a field for a specified document in MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using Nodejs and mongoDB as a backend service for my app.I have database structure given below:

```
{
  {
    _id:"1"
     Name:"Roy"
     Place:"Null"
  },

  {
    _id:"2"
     Name:"john"
     Place:"Ajmer"
  }
}
```

Here I want to check for a given **_id** if value of **Place** field is null or not.
**For Ex:** For **_id=2** value of a **Place** field is null or not.

Someone please help how to execute this query.

**THANKS**

Comment: First extract the data using your `_id`, and then check it manually. Make sense?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy could you please write query for the same as i am beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Mongoose to do this:

```
YourModel.find({ _id: idToCheck, Place: { $ne: null }}).then((res) => {
    if (res && res.length) {
        //Place is not null
    } 
})
```

Edit: You can also achieve this in Mongo but you have to parse the id

```
db.yourCollection.find({ _id: ObjectId(idToCheck), Place: { $ne: null }}).then((res) => {
    if (res && res.length) {
        //Place is not null
    } 
})
```

Comment: Could you please solve the same using MongoDb as i am not using Mongoose.

Comment: There is a similar method in Mongo (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), maybe you have to parse the id though if its a string, not sure about it